# Where are the nodes in Hyperledger Fabric deployed in the actual scenario?

Tags: deployment, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, because like a public blockchain, each computer is a node and can get all the ledger.

1. If three companies want to make a ledger using Fabric, which company should deploy these nodes?
2. If each enterprise has to deploy peer nodes, how should the endorsement peer and the commit peer be allocated, and where is the orderer node placed?
3. If you put them all in one place, is it decentralization?

Answer (score 0):

Great questions.

1. It really does not matter where companies deploy the nodes, could be on campus, could be in the cloud, all you need are IP addresses and ports. It is best to deploy peers in different locations to avoid a single point of failure. Maybe deploy a node on each major cloud provider and one on campus to minimize downtime.
2. The endorsement policies would require an endorsement from a peer of each of the organizations if it is a transaction that is important to all the orgs. Each organization has endorsement peers. Orderer nodes should also be deployed in a variety of places although orderers are not organization specific like endorsement peers. It is best practice to have a more than one orderer and then get consensus using Kafka or Raft. There are a number of algorithms that can be used.
3. Peers should not all be in the same place- only for a dev env

Comment: @aaron875499765 an up vote and answer selection would be nice, trying to build up my reputation points

Answer (score 0):

To add to your second question, with Fabric 1.4.1 and 2.0.0, you can now use Raft-based Ordering services, which support decentralized ordering nodes. Now multiple Organizations can run decentralized Orderer's as well as decentralized Peer's. Providing additional security against downtime, and compromise.